# sequelize group by with multiple fields results into sequelize error

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My query is as shown below :

```
 db.test.findAll({
            group: ['source'],
            attributes: ['source','source_id', [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'source'), 'count']],
            order: [[Sequelize.literal('count'), 'DESC']],
            raw: true
        }).then((sources) => {
            console.log('source is ' + sources);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('error i is ' + err);
        })
```

test.js

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const test = sequelize.define('test', {
        id: {primaryKey: true, type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, unique: true},
        source: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
        source_id: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},

    });

    return test
};
```

As soon as I run this query , it gives me this error :

`Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.test.source_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use source_id in the group by clause also. because here SQL get's confuse which source_id to pick from multiple. You have the groupBy source so it will pick but souce_id is still ambiguous

```
 db.test.findAll({
                group: ['source', 'source_id'],
                attributes: ['source','source_id', [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'source'), 'count']],
                order: [[Sequelize.literal('count'), 'DESC']],
                raw: true
            }).then((sources) => {
                console.log('source is ' + sources);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('error i is ' + err);
            })
```